# Django with Vue Tutorial

Tags: django, vue.js, vuetify.js

I know this probably isn't best place to ask this question but I am desperate. I made most of stuff I needed in Django, and now I need to figure out Vue. The problem I have is that I can't find any tutorial on how to pass data from Django to Vue. I was planning on using Vuetify, but I am open to suggestions. I am also new to Vue, so I don't understand it yet, can you refer me to some tutorial that will help me?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not familiar with Vue.js but I'd say that it really depends how much you want to use it. If it is only to improve few pages already rendered by Django, it should be easy. On the other hand, if you want to fully handle your frontend with it, this means you need to create an API on the backend (for example with Django Rest Framework)

Comment: Yea, I need to create an API, but I dont know how, and how to use it in Vue then.

Comment: Then you probably just need a Vue tutorial :)

Comment: Thank you all for your help, you have guided me in direction I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue is a frontend framework for bulding user interfaces. Django is a backend framework, so you need a way to get them to communicate together. This way can be REST.

So you have to study: Django, Django Rest Framework, vue.js and some tutorials for put things together. Maybe looking for: vue django rest, on google can help ([example](https://medium.com/@jrmybrcf/how-to-build-a-project-with-django-vuejs-create-a-rest-api-endpoint-b57374a89661)).

Answer (score 1):

With a simple Google search you can find lots of tutorials on how to build a Django API.

Did you have a look at Django REST Framework?